# List of all references to struct doxygen

Tags: c, struct, doxygen

I'm trying to build documentation using doxygen 1.8.8 based on a large set of structs, and would like for the documentation to reference not only which structs I'm having, but also where the structs are used.  Please note that the source code is constructed from an external system, where I do some search and replace to make it into a structure similar to the following:

```
struct intersect {
  int aValue;     
};

struct foo_intersect_SET {
  order next;
  foo owner;
  intersect member;
};

struct intersect_bar_SET {
  order next;
  intersect owner;
  bar member;
};

struct another_SET {
  order ascending;
  something owner;
  foo member;
  bar member2;
  intersect member3;
};
```

I can get doxygen to build documentation, but when searching for "intersect" it only shows "intersect" and "intersect_bar_SET", I would like it to also display the "foo_intersect_SET" and possibly "another_SET".

And also when viewing the "intersect" struct I would like to get a list where it is used, i.e. that it is used by both "foo_intersect_SET", "intersect_bar_SET" and "another_SET".

Do you know if either of these are possible using doxygen?

Comment: Are you sure that this is C? Looks more like C++, since your are omitting the `struct` keyword.

Comment: It could be either C or C++... :-) If it helps I can easily add the struct in front. doxygen doesn't seem to mind that the struct is not there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to address this, which I'm currently pursueing is to change the structs into classes, and using multiple inheritance to get the connections both ways. In other words I have to make a temporary version which currently looks something like:

```
class foo : protected another {
}

class bar : proteced intersect_bar, protected another {
}

class intersect : protected foo_intersect, protected another {
  int aValue;     
};

class foo_intersect : private foo {
  order next;
  foo o_foo;
  intersect m_intersect;
};

class intersect_bar : private intersect {
  order next;
  intersect o_intersect;
  bar m_bar;
};

class another : private something {
  order ascending;
  something o_something;
  foo m_foo;
  bar m_bar;
  intersect m_intersect;
};
```

This is not an ideal solution, but using the inheritance diagram and collaboration diagram I do get most of the information that I want out of it! One caveat is that the original set structure allows for circular definitions, which in turn leads to circular inheritance which of course is not legal...

Comment: You do not need to replace struct by class to support inheritance